# Wordpress Logged Out Users

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a link in my header.php file that disappears after a user logs in...So the link only shows for logged out users...Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your header.php file place this code

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } ?>
```

Place your link inside the { } where the ... is.

See [Function Reference - is_user_logged_in()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) and its related functions for more information.

Comment: After the { place a ?> and then before the } place a <?php

Comment: Example: <?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { ?> <a href="">Login To Bookmark</a> <?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
global $user_ID,$current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ( $user_ID ) { .. }
```

You can get the current user login.

Comment: Make sure you solution is better than the ones already posted before adding to the answer list.